# Using variable number of float arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a flexible constructor for my struct Polynomial :

```
struct Polynomial
{
    std::vector<float> coefficients;
    size_t degree;
};
```

The degree of the polynomial is variable.
What I would like is to have a constructor like

```
Polynomial(float... _coefficients);
```

I've tried variadic template :

```
template<float... Args>
Polynomial(Args... args);
```

But float is a non-type, so I've done :

```
template<typename... Args>
Polynomial(Args... args);
```

But this allow my coefficients to be anything, not realy what I want.
I know I could use :

```
Polynomial(size_t _degree, ...);
```

But it is really unsafe.

At the moment I'm using :

```
Polynomial(std::vector<float>);
```

But this force the call to be like :

```
Polynomial P({f1, f2, f3}); // with fn floats
```

So I would like to know if there is a good way to do this.

Thank you !

Comment: "But this force the call to be like" ... what is wrong with that? Imho accepting a vector is much more flexible for the caller than accpeting a variadic

Comment: ^That. What happens if you have a user input arbitrary coefficients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your way (a vector parameter, or better (IMHO) an initializer list) is a good way.

Another way (simple but with drawbacks) could be the use of narrowing to be sure that `Args...` are `float` or types that can be narrowed to `float`. Something like

```
struct Polinomial
 {
   std::vector<double>  v;
   std::size_t          degree;

   template <typename ... Args>
   Polinomial (Args const & ... args)
      : v { float{args}... }, degree { sizeof...(Args) }
    { }
 };
```

It's simple and works, by example

```
Polinomial p { 2.3f, 3.5f, 6.7f };
```

but your constructor doesn't accept, by example, integer or `double` or `long double` values; so

```
Polinomial p { 2.3f, 3.5f, 6.7 };
// ........................^^^  double, error

Polinomial p { 2.3f, 3.5f, 6 };
// ........................^  int, error
```

and probably is too restrictive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was what I tried to do but indeed it might me to restrictive, I'll see if I need other types but for the moment I think that it will be enought

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`initializer_list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Polynomial {
    std::vector<float> coeffs;
    std::size_t degree;

    Polynomial(std::initializer_list<float> init)
        : coeffs{ init }, degree(init.size()) { }
};

int main() {
    Polynomial p{ 1, 2, 3. };
}
```

Comment: Why constructor `Polynomial p{ 1, 2, 3. };` doesn't need `()`. Just asking, i have never seen that.

Comment: @alseether This is uniform initialization, it got added in C++11. You can look up all the initialization rules on the C++ reference, including the peculiarities of having a `initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the difference with @max66 solution. I think I will keep all three methods

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question

> I would like to know if there is a good way to do this

Yes, i think the way you are doing it it's more than acceptable. And even the syntax where you use it `Polynomial P({f1, f2, f3});` isn't so ugly at all.

Furthermore, use `std::vector` is as efficient as variadic and much more comprehensible for others.

With the variadic approach, you will find difficult to force those types received to be `float`, but with `std::vector` you got it controlled

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive template parameter processing. The general idea is to use a private method that adds first parameter to the `coefficient` vectors and recurse with other parameters until they have all been processed:

```
struct Polynomial
{
    template<class...Args>
    Polynomial(Args... coeffs) {
        init(coeffs...);
        degree = coefficients.size() - 1;
    }
    std::vector<float> coefficients;
    size_t degree;
private:
    void init(float coeff) {
        coefficients.push_back(coeff);
    }
    template<class...Args> void init(float first, Args...others) {
        init(first);
        init(others...);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. You might want to look at the constructors of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for inspiration. For example a templated constructor that takes two iterators is very flexible:

```
template<typename T>
Polynomial(T begin, T end) : coefficients(begin, end), degree(coefficients.size()) {}

auto init = std::vector<float>{2.0, 1.0, 4.0};
Polynomial p2{init.begin(), init.end()};
```

Or you could take a `std::initializer_list<float>` as Jodocus suggested.

You could have a templated constructor that takes any container type:

```
template<typename T>
Polynomial(T container) 
: coefficients(begin(container), end(container))
, degree(coefficients.size()) {}

auto init = std::vector<float>{2.0, 1.0, 4.0};
Polynomial p2{init};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8Au4ZJlEoUNNt0SG).

Or you could provide a combination of different constructors to suit different needs.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is a "good way". Imagine the caller wants to pass 100 coefficients. If you use variadics you force the caller to do something like that:

```
float c1,c2,c3,....c100;
// init them
Polynomial P(c1, c2, c3,....,c100);
```

If I was to use 100 coefficients I would certainly store them in a vector, and it would be rather cumbersome to pass them to your polynomial:

```
auto coeffs = std::vector<float>(100);
Polynomial P(coeffs[0],coeffs[1],....,coeffs[100]);
```

If however, you accept a vector, the caller can do both without pain:

```
Polynomial P({c1,c2,c2});
Polynomial P(coeffs);
```

On the other hand, using `std::vector` but not allowing a different container is an arbitrary restriction. The better way then would be to accept iterators, and let the caller do:

```
Polynomial P(coeffs.begin(),coeffs.end());
```